# Ant media server: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError

Tags: java, linux, java-8, red5, ant-media-server-sdk

I have downloaded the installation files of the ant media server and now I am following this [tutorial](https://antmedia.io/webrtc-live-video-stream-broadcasting-one-to-many-and-watching-with-rtmp-and-hls/) to try to run the server.
So I've run this command:

> ./start.sh

But, I keep getting this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
> org/red5/server/Bootstrap has been compiled by a more recent version
> of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the
> Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 53.0

Here's the whole stack trace:
[image]

Running java -version gives me this:
[image]

Running javac -version gives me this:
[image]

The OS info is:
[image]

Any idea what's going-on?

---

I have tried installing java 8 by following the commands [here](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=292930):
[image]
So now when I run `java -version`, I get this:
[image]
But, I still get the same error.

---

FYI, when I run this command:

> sudo update-alternatives --config java

This is what I get:
[image]
I have selected option 1.
I have run the same commands for `javac`.
So now when I run `java -version`, I have this:
[image]
And when I run `javac -version`, I have this:
[image]
And I am still getting the same error.

---

The `JAVA_HOME` environment variable is also set to:

> JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle

Comment: Your application includes JAR files built for Java 11.  (version 55).  You should be running the application using a Java 11 (or later) JVM.  Java 8 (version 52) won't work.  And nor will Java 9 (version 53).

Comment: And ... on re-reading your question ... it is not "your" application.  It is a 3rd-party application whose installation instructions **neglect** to say that it requires Java 11.  (This isn't really a programming question at all.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling you that the class was compiled with a newer version than the one you're running.

You need to run it with Java 11 (version 55) but you are using Java 9 (version 53).